# Sharepoint 2007 Not updating Username, resulting in not sending email notifications

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We are running Sharepoint 2007 here and I recently changed a number of details for one user's account in Active Directory (she changed her last name).  I left her account name the same (lets say jsmith).  So, she went from Jane Smith to Jane Jones, but her user account and login name is still jsmith.

Everywhere in Active Directory and windows-related stuff, her name is properly updated and displayed as Jane Jones.  Sharepoint though, does not.  In addition, we have a couple issue management tracker lists which she is part of, and she no longer receives the same email notifications she used to (in fact, as far as I can tell, she doesn't get any emails from Sharepoint).

How do I force Sharepoint to update its user list, and why does changing a user's active directory account seem to result in Sharepoint not sending the user emails anymore?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to your Central Administration on the local server, navigate to SSP (Shared Services Provider), and go to your "Users and Profiles".
- From there you can do a "Full Crawl" and that should fix your issue.

Active Directory uses the username "firstinitallastname@domain.com" in order to send emails, when you changed it, SharePoint used the cached user profiles list, so you will have to re-crawl it.

Comment: Agree with @Mike as this is most likely the problem.  Don't forget to schedule regular imports of this data to avoid this issue in the future.